# batch/perl/python to find a string in multiple files and then delete row

Tags: python, perl, batch-file

I recently stumble across this problem and I did not manage to solve it since I am new to this  scripting method.
I need a script that does the following :

Based on a list (list.txt) search every row from that text into multiple files and if found delete that row (from eevery other file).
I tried to save the list.txt as an array and go through it with a for , but I do not know how to search the string and delete the row.
Can you please help me with this issue ?

So far this is what I came up with from multiple sources :

REPL.bat that searches into multiple text files :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::REPL  /V
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /?, then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /V, case insensitive, then prints
:::  the version of REPL.BAT. (Currently 3.1)
:::
:::  Search  - By default, this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default, this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::
:::            For example, $& represents the portion of the source that matched
:::            the entire search pattern, $1 represents the first captured
:::            submatch, $2 the second captured submatch, etc. A $ literal
:::            can be escaped as $$.
:::
:::            An empty replacement string must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is fully documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            V - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            A - Only print altered lines. Unaltered lines are discarded.
:::                This option is incompatible with the M option.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line, thus enabling
:::                search for \n. This option is incompatible with the A option.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences within the Replace string:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \q     -  Quote
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Also enables the \q escape sequence for the Search string.
:::                The other escape sequences are already standard for a regular
:::                expression Search string.
:::
:::                Also modifies the behavior of \xnn in the Search string to work
:::                properly with extended ASCII byte codes.
:::
:::                Extended escape sequences are supported even when the L option
:::                is used. Both Search and Replace support all of the extended
:::                escape sequences if both the X and L opions are combined.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string. Without
:::                the M option, ^ anchors the beginning of the string, and $ the
:::                end of the string. With the M option, ^ anchors the beginning
:::                of a line, and $ the end of a line.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    <"%~f0" cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" "" a
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/V" (
    echo REPL.BAT version 3.1
    exit /b
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEBVXA]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "M"|findstr /i "A" >nul && (
  call :err "Incompatible options"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var alterations=(options.indexOf("a")>=0);
if (alterations) options=options.replace(/a/g,"");
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
if (options.indexOf("v")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/v/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  search=search.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  search=search.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  search=search.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  search=search.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  search=search.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  search=search.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  search=search.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  search=search.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  search=search.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  search=search.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  search=search.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  search=search.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  search=search.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  search=search.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
    search=search.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
    search=search.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
    search=search.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
    search=search.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
    search=search.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
    search=search.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
    search=search.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
      function($0,$1,$2){
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
      }
    );
    search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  } else search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\\\");
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);
var str1, str2;

if (srcVar) {
  str1=env(args.Item(3));
  str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
  if (!alterations || str1!=str2) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      str1=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
      str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
      if (!alterations || str1!=str2) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
    }
  }
}
```

I created this for going over all files (user def function with 2 arguments)

```
   :myBatchFunc
    for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    type "%%F"|repl %~1 %~2 >"%%F.new"
    move /y "%%F.new" "%%F" 
    )
```

This would be my main batch from where I call and run everything.

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\ecatser\Desktop\RPS_cells\EXCEPTII.log"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call myBatchFunc %%array[%%i]%% x
PAUSE
```

I do realise this is a lot of code for a very easy task , can anyone provide me with a better answer for batch/perl/python ? 
Thank you in advance.

P.S (plus the script I have right now replaces the string with ' x '. So it is not deleting the row.

---

EDIT :
The situation is as follows :
I have 1 directory with contains list.log (which is basically a list of exceptions), and a bunch of other .txt files.

list.log example :

```
 53737
 52505         // this value matches the cell in .txt
 13211
 21412
 21313
 23123
```

.txt file example

```
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell52505      // the cell with the same value 
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell20774
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell22312
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell20233
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell12322
```

Output .txt file :

```
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell20774      // 52505 was removed
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell22312
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell20233
 LOTS_OF_USELESS_TEXT,Cell=cell12322
```

So, I want the script to read the list.log line by line take each value/string and look for it in every .txt file from that directory and IF found delete that row from the file and overwrite IF not found go to next value/row from list.log.
Basically the .txt files are a list of cells and the list.log is a list of exceptions and I want to delete the exceptions from the .txt files.

I hope I explained well this time .

Comment: Ok I made it work eventually but it is a lot of code for something easy :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
perl -ani.back -e 'print unless /The text to be search/' list_of_files_to_process
```

This will delete lines that contain `The text to be search` and save the original file with th extension `.back`.

**Edit**

```
perl -ani.back -e 'BEGIN{open $fh,"f.log";@l=<$fh>;chomp@l;$r=join("|",@l)}print unless /\b$r\b/' *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, the problem is that the "Text to be searched" has to be loaded from a file(list.txt let's say). So for instance it takes first line from list.log and looks for that string in the .txt files and deletes the row where the string was found,and so on for next line from list

Comment: @cserbanesc: I'm not sure I understand your needs. Could you edit your question and add some sample input files and the expected result?

Comment: I edited the question as requested , I hope this time I explained it well enough ! :)

Comment: I tried it and from what I can tell it works but it deletes the row in the wrong files (it deletes the row containing the string from list.log not from .txt files)

Comment: @cserbanesc: It seems strange as it works fine for me. May be you have to remove the `\b` from the regex, but be aware that if you have `12` in file.log it will remove lines that contain `12` and `abc12` and `12345` ...

Comment: Ok , it works with \b removed. Thank you very much M42 !

Answer (score 1):

Using python the following should work. It uses regular expressions. The list of patterns is read and the patterns are joined using "OR" to one large regular expression. Then every file is read line per line and if the pattern does NOT match, the line is written to a new file, otherwise not. The script expects the first command line argument to be the pattern file and all subsequent arguments the names of the files to be processed.

```
import re 
import sys
# patternfile contains a list of patterns, one per row
# this lines are striped (linebreaks removed) and joined using "OR" regex
with open(sys.argv[1]) as patternfile:
  pattern=re.compile('|'.join(map(strip,patternfile.readlines())))
# loop over all files given
for f in sys.argv[2:]:
    with open(f,'r') as infile:    
        fout = infile.name + '.new'
        # open outfile with new name
        with open(infile.name, 'w') as outfile:
            # loop over lines
            for line in f:
                # check if pattern matches
                if re.search(pattern,line)==None: #pattern does not match
                    outfile.write(line)
```

The script has to be adapted to delete the original file if necessary.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply ! This python script as you said "every file is read line per line and if the pattern does NOT match, the line is written to a new file, otherwise not". I need something more like : "every file is read line per line and if pattern matches delete the line from that file ELSE read next line/value from the pattern list"

Comment: The question has been marked as answered, still I'd like to update on that. By joining the patterns, you search your lines by all patterns simulationously. You read all patterns once and than search for them in all lines of the files. Furthermore you always mention to delete the line within the original file but you can also create a new file without the matching lines. Afterwards you can move that new file to the position of the old one if you like.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. This was my mistake (I am sorry, I misread), the answer offered by you is correct as well can I make mark both as answers ? Thank you very much, I find you answer very useful.

Comment: There's only one correct answer possible, but that's fine.